# Gulp + Browsersync watch css file for reload

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

I am trying to use browsersync and gulp with mamp. It's working to watch my php files but im unable to get the watch on my css file working. I dont want gulp to run my sass files i only want it to watch to handle the reloading and browsersync with. How can i get this to work?

my gulpfile.js file

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('default', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "http://localhost:8888/"
    });
    gulp.watch("./public/themes/site/*.php").on("change", browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: gulp.watch("./public/themes/site/*.css").on("change", browserSync.reload);

Comment: @DanielTate Thank you, in my mind the procedure was very complicated, hehe.